# brew install hadoop installing 2.8.1 version. But needed 2.7.4 version

Tags: hadoop, installation, homebrew

I have Homebrew 1.3.1
I want to install hadoop 2.7 but brew is installing hadoop 2.8 version.
I tried 
brew versions, which is not available anymore.
brew tap homebrew/version, which is now deprecated.

In previous brew version, we were able to use brew tap homebrew/boneyard and then brew versions work. But, now even from homebrew/boneyard the versions command is removed.

Would we good to know the direct command for homebrew to run and install hadoop 2.7.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(@bfontaine its not a duplicate question as that answer is 6 years ago and no longer works)

You can try running

```
brew list --versions hadoop
```

to see if you have previous versions and you can switch to it by running

```
brew switch hadoop 2.7.4
```

There is

```
brew install <package_name>@<version>
```

Unfortunately it seems hadoop and many other packages haven't set it up to be possible to download the older version and I haven't found out a way to do it.

Comment: ["Error: Unknown command: switch"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66082776/uncommon-homebrew-error-unknown-command-switch)

Answer (score 1):

As I am writing this, there is a version 2.7.7 of hadoop here: https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/hadoop/common/

You can use 'brew edit hadoop' to refer to that version directly, and then run 'brew install hadoop'.

Comment: thanks! @jon This approach really helped but for a different version. How to revert back to make it point to the latest after installation?