# Uncommon homebrew error: "Unknown command: switch"

Tags: openssl, homebrew, macos-catalina

I am in the process of trying to restart some legacy project that demands the use of an older version of openssl.

I have found good input on the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61086871/921573), which worked on one of my machines but not the other, which gives me the following error:

```
$  brew switch openssl 1.0.2t
Error: Unknown command: switch
```

The error does not seem to be very common, nothing helpful is showing up on a google/stackoverflow search.

What I have tried so far:

- resolved all warnings shown by `brew doctor`
- run `brew update && brew upgrade`
- updated Xcode Command Line Tools
- reinstalled openssl

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I haven't found a workaround yet either, but I'm encountering the exact same issue :( Apparently, homebrew got rid of the `switch` command very recently: https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/339

Comment: I am having this exact same problem. And this seems like a poor decision on Homebrew crews part to remove switch with no "hey use this instead" error..sigh.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As I commented above, [Homebrew got rid of the `switch` command](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/339) entirely, which is why it says "Unknown command".

But rbenv provides a tap that you can install openssl from. You can run the command below:

```
brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0
```

If you're installing openssl@1.0 for Ruby purposes, [this thread](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1353#issuecomment-573414540) tells you how to do that as well. For example:

```
CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.0)" RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.0)" rbenv install 2.7.2
```

Comment: this works for 2.7.2 but surprising not for 2.6.5

Answer (score 0):

Brew disabled "switch" command. Use "link" instead:

```
brew link openssl@1.1
```

Answer (score -3):

I just used sudo:

```
sudo brew switch dart 2.16.0
```

and close the vs code and start again.
That's it and run without any errors.

Comment: your comment is not relevant because you use old version of brew

Comment: NEVER do this, by doing `sudo brew` "you would be giving all
build scripts full access to your system" (from documentation).